# Use generating functions to find $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Use generating functions to find $a_{n}$ if:

$a_{n} =6n+a_{n−1}$, for $n≥1$ and $a_{0} =0$

I tried to divide it into two separate sums $\sum_{m=1}^\infty 6mx^m $ and $\sum_{l=1}^\infty a_{l-1}x^l $

I have managed with the left sided sum, but then I realized that on the right side I do have sequence in a sum and now I am a bit confused and I don't have idea what to do now.

Comment: Dont forget that you are looking for $f(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}a_l x^l$, so does the right sum look any similar to this? Can you express it in terms of $f(x)$? (hint: try to reindex right sum to go from $0$)

Comment: Is the answer $f(x) = 6x$  / $(1-x)^{3}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Good job!